# Bookdown "Remark" environment

Tags: r, bookdown

I'm trying to add numbered remarks (like in the definition or theorem environments) that I could referenced in a bookdown document. Something like:

````
```{remark, mylab}
my comment
```

In Remark \@ref(rem:mylab) we discussed...
````

which would produce:

Remark 1.1 my comment

In Remark 1.1 we discussed ...

Would anyone know if this is possible? Also, is it possible to change the numbering to A, B and so on? That is to have instead:

Remark A my comment

In Remark A we discussed ...

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you looking for a general solution or LaTeX/PDF only?

Comment: Hi Ralf, I'm mainly interested in a html output but of course a general solution would be great. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general solution is:

- Choose one of the [predefined theorem like environments](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#theorems) that you are not using otherwise, e.g. `example`.
- Redefine the printed name for that environment in `_bookdown.yml` (c.f. https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/internationalization.html) via:

  ```
  language:
    label:
      exm: 'Remark '
  ```
- In your `Rmd` files use

  ````
  ```{example, mylab}
  my comment
  ```

  In Remark \@ref(exm:mylab) we discussed...
  ````

  Note that you have to use `example` and the correspoding label prefix `exm`.

I do not know of a general solution to use alphabetic instead of numeric numbering. I am sure that this would be possible if one would use only LaTeX/PDF output.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user304347 You are welcome. Feel free to accept/up-vote the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: @RalfStubner Thanks for the idea. Where can I find the _bookdown.yml file or do I have to create it myself?

Comment: @CarolEisen That's a configuration file that you place in the main directory. See https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/configuration.html#configuration.